# Config menu looks weird

Tags: texmaker

[image]

Dear all,

I'm totally new to LateX, can anyone, please, explain why one part of Configuration menu looks jammed? (Picture below) 
How can I fix it?
Appreciate your advice

Comment: Does the weird effect go away if you enlarge the window slightly by dragging the lower right border (https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001478.htm)? If the issue does not go away and you are bothered by this you should report this to the TeXmaker developers: http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/#contact

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Resizing helped indeed, although I tried it earlier and it did nothing :) Magic...